# Java check Phone number and matches

Tags: java, android, regex

i want to check below phone number with `matches`, phone number conditions :

1. start with 0 or 9
2. content must be between 0 and 9
3. phone number must be 10 character

I tried:

```
String mobile_number = "9371236569";
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mobile_number) && 
    mobile_number.matches("^[0][9][0-9]{10}$")) {
}
```

For number `9371236569` dont work my code and return false,

Comment: "[09][0-9]{9}" this regex can be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ ] Matches any single character in brackets except range with `-`.
`mobile_number.matches("^[09][0-9]{9}$")`

`^[09]`    start with eighter 0 or 9.
`[0-9]{9}` rest 9 digits raging from 0-9.

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex:

`"^(0|9)[0-9]{9}$"`

Explanation:

`^` match beginning of the string

`(0|9)` match one digit either a 0 or a 9

`[0-9]{9}` match 9 digits in the range of 0-9

`$` match end of the string

Comment: Thanks sir, `9371236569` is 10 character, why you write `{9}`, after start with `0` or `9` calculate it?

Comment: The first digit is handled specially because it can only be 0 or 9. Then the remaining 9 digits are handled separately to give 10 in total.

Comment: [0|9] means either 0 , | or 9. here `|` behaves as single char not `OR`. input __`|371236561`__ returns __true__

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean validateMobile(String moblieNumber) {
    boolean check;
    Pattern p;
    Matcher m;
    String MobilePattern = "[0-9]{10}";
    p = Pattern.compile(MobilePattern);

    m = p.matcher(moblieNumber);
    check = m.matches();
    return check;
}
```

Comment: Please add more details, since code-only and try-this answers should explain the reason they address the question.